# Apache SOLR + Facet API + Taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

I want to create a product catalog and I have been told that apache SOLR could be the best way to go. I installed Drupal Commerce, Apache SOLR Integration (7.x-1.0-rc2) and Facet API (7.x-1.0).
I added a custom field "category" to my product display content type which refers to a hierarchical taxonomy vocabulary.

- Clothing

  - Tops
  - Dresses
  - Skirts
- Accessories

  - Bags
  - Jewelery
- Shoes

  - Pumps
  - Sneakers

On my products page I would like to see a facet block where I can select my categories.
I want to show my top level categories without their children at first, but when you select a category I also want to see its' children. You can achieve this functionality with the standard installation I believe.

BUT when I select one top level category (Clothing) my other top level categories disappear (Accessories, Shoes).
I don't want to be able to select multiple top level categories at once, I just want them to be visible...
Is that possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Although I've not tried the recipe I believe that [this article over at wunderkraut](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/build-advanced-content-listings-with-apache-solr-search-api-facet-api/2012-04-20) is an exact match for what you are after. There is a lot of custom coding involved.